# Making a file executable on a by the work place locked Mac

Tags: python, selenium, security, development-environment

I have a Macbook pro that I have received from work. I want to run my webscraper with selenium. However the moment I call the webscraper from my Python code I get the following errors:

1. In a window: “chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
   macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.
   Chrome downloaded this file today at 09:24 from chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
2. In the terminal: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9

I have already:

- Moved the file (chromedriver executable) to different directories (username/bin, usr/bin, usr/local/bin) that are in my PATH env.
- Tried to unlock execution via mac interface via the instructions in this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491
- Changed the file characteristics with "sudo chmod 777 chromedriver"
- Contacted my work ICT department. They don't want to remove the lock.

Is there a way to work around this lock? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Either your scraper is needed for work in which case you just escalate to your supervisor, or the scraper isn't needed for work in which case feel free to risk your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find a vulnerability in mac or the softwares that are already installed in your mac. check cvedetails.com, any other website like that is fine, they synchronize their database.
But before doing so, you should know that this is policy is forced with your network admin. It means there is an agent already installed on your mac that is reporting the current status of mac to admin. If you break it then it will report it. You might loose your job.

Comment: Awesome thanks man! Im gonna use my old mac, don't want to risk losing my job